# Deploy Ionic 4 App to Apache sever

Tags: ionic-framework, deployment, ionic4

I'm trying to deploy the new Ionic 4 app to an Apache server. I have ran.

```
ionic serve
```

to make sure it builds locally
Then I ran

```
ionic build
```

Then ran

```
ionic build --prod
```

This was to produce the production files in www.
But when I upload the files to the server and go to the index.html file it shows nothing. I keep getting errors in the console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found) runtime.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found) polyfills.js

and four other errors.

Any help would be great.

Comment: How does your distribution looks like ? does it have minimized versions of app and vendor js files ?

Comment: It has a vendor.js file and they are not minimized but I don't see an app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the "baseHref" so that you get the files correctly.
Surely you have a directory is your app.
For example. http://yourdomain.com/ionicApp
In this case you would have to define in the index.html file: